# Query not returning results - filtering on Date field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which attempts to return all records from MYTABLE between a pair of dates.

An example date stored in the database is  : 2013-04-10 15:42:10.096789

The below Query executes for approx 30 mins but does not seem to return, the size of MYTABLE is 200'000 rows .

Is my query correct ?

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE('2013-04-01 00:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND TIMESTAMP <= TO_DATE('2013-04-30 00:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY REP_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Could the level of detail the date being stored at (6 decimal places) be an issue of this Query ?

Comment: It would be a little more consistent to use `to_timestamp` rather than `to_date`, assuming your column is actually of type `timestamp(6)` as you suggest; you're doing a trivial implicit conversion (which should have no effect no index use etc.). How are you executing this, and are you interrupting it? Is `MYTABLE` really a table, or is it a view on a much large table? Do other queries return as expected in the same session, e.g. `count(*) from mytable`?

Answer (score 1):

2013-05-10 15:42:10.096789 is outside your date range that you're querying for. Your query is going to only return results from April 2014, but 2013-05-10 15:42:10.096789 is in May 2013.

By the way, if you're using Oracle, you can use the between clause. That makes it a little easier to read. I'm not sure if that syntax is supported in other database software.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
  AND TIMESTAMP '2013-04-30 00:00:00'
ORDER BY REP_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Also, my post has been edited to reflect that since you're using the ISO standard format, you can use the timestamp literal instead of using the TO_DATE function.

Comment: ive updated my question to show a sample date that falls within the specified range. This date is not being returned. So my query is correct albeit not using the BETWEEN keyword ?

Comment: The between keyword was only shown to illustrate a simpler syntax. It's entirely correct that you can use  the `<=` syntax if you want.

Comment: The new date you have posted does fall between the date range you specified and would be returned. 200,000 rows or not, that query should not take 30 minutes. You've got something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The date you are searching for does not fall in the range you're searching in.  Either flip-flop the `>=` and `<=` or choose a different date.